# VisualStudio 2010 C++ color theme

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, themes

I really do need some help with something?

How can I change the color of User Type variables(doesn't matter if it's a struct, class whatever will be) in VS2010 C++?

I've tried to change it manually, with changing scheme, theme... anything and nothing was working.

Is it possible and if so, how? Or is just possible in 2015 or c#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the tools->options menu and then go to 'fonts and colors' under the environment section. Then, change the display items for the 'text editor'.

[image]

Comment: If would be so simple... I wouldn't ask this question in the first place. What are you showing me there is not working in VS2010 C++ or.. something is wrong for me.  I've chosen different colors but even so.. in the case when for example you have something like this `struct ddd{ ddd* so;};` that "ddd" will be white, the same will be for classes also and all of the User Types. Doesn't matter the color I choose. So do you have any other suggestion?